# USB-PD over USB-A

Tags: usb-device, usb-c, wireless-charging, usb-pd, power-delivery

I have a power adapter from Samsung which supports an output of 5.0V 2.0A or 9.0V 1.67A. The adapter has a USB-A output and fast charges my S10 at 9V. Can USB-A be used for USB-PD?

I also have a wireless fast charger what outputs 9V and but has a USB-C male input wire with 5 wires inside it: red, blue, white, green and blue. I know that the red, black, green and white wires are used in USB communication and but not sure what the blue wire does.
To learn more, I carried out a simple experiment. I cut the wire and connected only red and black wires and measured 0V across them. This was the same when the white and green wires were connected and the blue wire was left out.
I then connected only red, black and blue and suddenly I was measuring 9V between red and black, and 1.55v between black and blue. I noticed that the blue wire was connected to the wireless charger control board and was labelled 'CC' and there was another unconnected 'CC' wire.
The CC wire is used for USB-PD negotiation and is required to communicate with the host and set the correct voltage for power delivery and the D+, and D- wires have nothing to do with this.

My Xiaomi power bank also has a USB-A output and it mentions that the USB-A port can output 5V, 9V and 12V at up to 2A. I am now trying to replace the USB-C port on my wireless charger to a USB-A male connector so I can use it in my car, with my power bank and even my laptop if needed.
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

USB Type-A does not have a CC pin so it does not support PD.

Other stanards such as QuickCharge are used over the USB Type-A connector data wires to negotiate higher voltages.

So both your Type-C device and Type-A device would have to support these standards to work over USB-C to USB-A cable.

If your car has a Type-A socket and it only supports 5V and no QC, then it never outputs anything else than 5V.

Comment: @AdityaDesai I already explained, it uses other standards than PD, but not PD. You asked if PD is used over USB-A and it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

USB-A connectors, do not inherently support the power negotiation features required by USB-PD. USB-A connectors have fixed pin arrangements and lack the necessary communication lines (CC1 and CC2) for negotiating power levels dynamically.

As a result, USB-PD cannot be directly implemented over a traditional USB-A connection.